# React Router in Azure IIS Rewrite

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-router, iisnode

I have a few routes in my React app that accept a GUID value as a parameter. For instance, a user receives an email with a link and follows that link to verify and activate their account on the site.

```
<Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
<Route path="/register/:id" component={RegistrationConfirmation} />
```

When I deploy this app to Azure, I am able to serve the page through express and navigate to `http://[mysiteUrl]/register` but static links provided in confirmation emails yield 404 errors.

Here is my current web.config from the `site/wwwroot` folder:

```
 <rules>
     <rule name="Rewrite Text Requests" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
             <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="^text/html" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^api/" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/index.html" />
     </rule>
     <rule name="register" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^/register/*" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
     </rule>
 </rules>
```

This doesn't work and looks like it just attempts to navigate to a separate page in the same location:
[image: routeError]

What is the correct way to configure this file so that I can serve up parameterized routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so the issue was pretty stupid, but I did manage to get it sorted. The issue was the route resolution in the `index.html`

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Had to be changed to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Here's my final web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="./app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
     <rule name="React Requests">
         <match url="/*" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="^text/html" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="./dist/index.html" />
     </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Should be noted that I'm not leaving anything up to Express. All the routing is handled here.