# URL Rewrite not working - React SPA on Azure Web App (node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, url-rewriting

I'm running a create-react-app build on an Azure Web App (node LTS). The app uses React Routes, and runs great from the index screen and as long as you are navigating the route links through the app. However, if you refresh a page, or navigate directly to a non-root route, you get 404. It seems to me like my web.config rewrite (of which I've tried many variations) is not being honored. I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

**index.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
    index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**web.config (edit with updated version)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <webSocket enabled="false" />
 <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
  </handlers>
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="React Routes">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="True"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/api" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <remove segment="bin"/>
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

File Structure (/site/wwwroot/)

- index.html
- web.config
- static/ (css, js)

Comment: take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978338/react-router-in-azure-iis-rewrite

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks for that, unfortunately still stuck. I have attempted a similar approach, and am effectively bypassing node/express altogether for routing. I still have the same issue where I can navigate fine through app links, but refresh or direct access via url gives a 404. Editing with most recent version of web.config.

Comment: this is kind of a "common" problem when dealing with SPA. whatever url /#/custom-link IIS will try to serve.